# Which docker container choose for a django application in production

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker.
I saw existing images like one called "django" on docker hub.
It sounds great but i see this image is working with django integrated server on 8000 http port.
So i am wondering if this docker prebuilt image is for development purpose instead of production.
Which prebuilt image should i use for production ?

Thanks

Comment: why dont you configure your own container?

Answer (score 0):

The [django image on the Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/django/) is an official repository, which means it's curated, security checked and maintained by Docker - so it's a trustworthy source.

You wouldn't use it on its own though. You'd run your web app in a Django container and then front it with a reverse proxy like Nginx, running in another container. The outside world talks to your proxy, and your proxy talks to Django.

[There are detailed docs](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#configure-nginx-for-your-site) on using Nginx as a reverse proxy for Django.

Comment: I know reverse proxy but i actually do this manualy, without docker. What i am looking for is a procedure (docker-compose or docker file) for creating and configuring everything. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](https://github.com/andrecp/django-tutorial-docker-nginx-postgres)